# nestjs - neovim [import-prefix-missing no-local: Unable to load a local module] error

Tags: typescript, nestjs, neovim

This is an annoying problem as it doesn't effect the running of the program but when opening up a fresh (or existing) NestJS application all imports are flagged as an error
for example, if we look at the `main.ts` file there are two imports:

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core' // <-- (1)
import { AppModule } from './app.module'   // <-- (2)
```

error 1:

> import-prefix-missing: Relative import path "@nestjs/core" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../ from "file:///Users/me/Documents/hello-world/src/main.ts

error 2:

> no-local: Unable to load a local module: "file:///Users/me/Documents/hello-world/src/app.module".   Please check the file path.

these errors are not shown in VSCode or in WebStorm
When googling these errors they are related to Deno/Python, I don't have `Deno` installed but python2 and python3 are installed for Neovim

when running the application there is no errors and runs just fine, but I don't get this error when using `Express` or `Koa` with or without typescript. This issue is only with NestJS.

Answer (score 1):

The linters can be set manually in `.vimrc`. There the 'deno' linter can be left out for typescript:

```
".vimrc
...
let g:ale_linters = { 'typescript': ['eslint', 'tsserver', 'typecheck'] }
```

As described in here: https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale#faq-disable-linters

`:ALEInfo` then says:

```
 Current Filetype: typescript
Available Linters: ['deno', 'eslint', 'standard', 'tslint', 'tsserver', 'typecheck', 'xo']
  Enabled Linters: ['eslint', 'tsserver', 'typecheck']
  Ignored Linters: []
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the computer that I am using *DID* have Deno installed and was processing it and there was a conflict. So I will need to find a way how to configure this with NeoVim. I figured this out by running the command `:ALEDetail` and provided additional information from where:

> [deno] : mport-prefix-missing: Relative import path "@nestjs/core" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../ from "file:///Users/me/Documents/hello-world/src/main.ts

my fault